# Brake not hard anymore?

Tags: brakes

On engine off, when brake is depressed and released several times, eventually it becomes hard. As soon as engine is started, it becomes soft. This is normal. However, recently, even when off it doesn't come hard even after several times of depressed. I can even do the play at any moment. There's no leakages, sounds etc. Fluids everything ok.

Comment: Does it feel right when you drive it?  It might be a bad master cylinder.

Comment: The system may need to be bled.  Air in the lines will cause a spongy pedal regardless if it is running.

Comment: While engine is running, everything is ok and no issues with braking. All perfect. But, when off, it doesn't come hard eventually.